# The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared.

Tags: php, html

I am keep getting following error when executing php code

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/a9440109/public_html/gps_list.php on line 37

I have tried to define character encoding but still getting the error. Please let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
 <?php
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 //connect to the database

 include ('gps_db_connect.php');

 $query = "SELECT * from gps WHERE server_time > '20130130'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(' Error getting data');
 echo $query;


 $row_count = 0;
 $color_switch = 0;
 $td_size=1;
 $td_font='Verdana'';

 echo "<table border = 1 WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1 >";
 echo "<tr> <th>Count</th><th>User/Device ID</th><th>Longitude, Latitude</th>        <th></th> <th> Speed</th>  <th> Direction </th> <th> GPS Date/Time</th> <th> Server Time </th></tr>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 if ( $color_switch == 0 ) {
     $bg_color="#FFFFFF";

     $color_switch = 1;
  }

 else {

     $bg_color="#D8D8D8";
         $color_switch = 0;
         }
     $row_count++;
     echo "<tr><td bgcolor=$bg_color> <font size=$td_size face=$td_font>";
     echo $row_count;

         echo "</td><td bgcolor=$bg_color>  <font size=$td_size face=$td_font> &nbsp";
         echo $row['gps_user'];

     echo "</td><td bgcolor=$bg_color>  <font size=$td_size face=$td_font> &nbsp";
     echo $row['gps_lng'].','.$row['gps_lat'];


     echo "</td></tr>";


    }
 echo "</table>";

 ?>
```

Comment: You get a PHP syntax error and you are trying to fix it by setting the encoding of something instead of fixing the syntax error?

Comment: `$td_font='Verdana'';` has an extra `'` at the end. Still, too localized for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$td_font='Verdana'';
```

has an extra quote at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that and error message threw me off.

Comment: Is there any HTML / PHP syntax error check utility?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:   `$td_font='Verdana'';` with  `$td_font='Verdana';`